# Java - Dúvida sobre Sincronização de Threads

Tags: java

Eu tenho as seguintes classes:

Veículo (Vehicle):

```
public class Vehicle {

    private String chassis;
    private String type;
    private double topSpeed;

    public Vehicle() {

    }

    public Vehicle(String chassis, String type, double topSpeed) {
        super();
        this.chassis = chassis;
        this.type = type;
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
    }

    public void clean() {
        System.out.println(">> O veículo do tipo [" + getType() + "] está sendo limpo.");
    }

    public void adjust() {
        System.out.println(">> O veículo do tipo [" + getType() + "] está sendo ajustado.");
    }

    public int incrementalSpeed(int value) {
        return (int) (value + getTopSpeed());
    }

    public String getChassis() {
        return chassis;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public double getTopSpeed() {
        return topSpeed;
    }

    public void setTopSpeed(double topSpeed) {
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
    }

}
```

Competidor (Competitor):

```
public class Competitor implements Runnable {

    private Vehicle vehicle;
    private String name;
    private int pitStopTime;

    public Competitor(Vehicle vehicle, String name) {
        super();
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startRace();
    }

    public void startRace() {
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println(">> O veículo de nome " + getName() + " e do tipo " + vehicle.getType() + " iniciou a corrida.");

            try {
                for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    if(i == 1) {
                        System.out.println(">> O veículo de nome " + getName() + " e do tipo " + vehicle.getType() + " acabou de percorrer sua primeira volta.");

                        if(vehicle.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Carro")) {
                            setPitStopTime(1500);
                            Thread.sleep(getPitStopTime());
                        } else {
                            setPitStopTime(950);
                            Thread.sleep(getPitStopTime());
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(">> O veículo de nome " + getName() + " e do tipo " + vehicle.getType() + " percorreu " + i + " voltas.");
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException exception) {
                System.out.println(">> O veículo de nome " + getName() + " e do tipo " + vehicle.getType() + " teve um problema durante a volta.");
            }

            System.out.println(">> O veículo de nome " + getName() + " e do tipo " + vehicle.getType() + " terminou a corrida.");
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setPitStopTime(int pitStopTime) {
        this.pitStopTime = pitStopTime;
    }

    public int getPitStopTime() {
        return pitStopTime;
    }

}
```

Race (Corrida):

```
public class Race {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread firstCompetitor = new Thread(new Competitor(new Vehicle(null, "Bicicleta", 5), "Aitor"));
        Thread secondCompetitor = new Thread(new Competitor(new Vehicle(null, "Carro", 5), "Anderson"));
        Thread thirdCompetitor = new Thread(new Competitor(new Vehicle(null, "Carro", 5), "Gabriel"));
        Thread fourthCompetitor = new Thread(new Competitor(new Vehicle(null, "Bicicleta", 5), "Eduardo"));
        Thread fifthCompetitor = new Thread(new Competitor(new Vehicle(null, "Bicicleta", 5), "Angela"));
        Thread sixthCompetitor = new Thread(new Competitor(new Vehicle(null, "Carro", 5), "José"));

        firstCompetitor.start();
        secondCompetitor.start();
        thirdCompetitor.start();
        fourthCompetitor.start();
        fifthCompetitor.start();
        sixthCompetitor.start();
    }

}
```

Se trata de uma corrida com diversos competidores (que são veículos), cada competidor possui um nome e um tempo de pitstop, se for carro, o tempo é de 1500 milisegundos, já se for bicicleta, 950 milisegundos.

Utilizei um bloco de sincronização no meu método startRace() mas nada acontece. Segundo meu conhecimento sobre sincronização de Threads, a Thread que chamar o método só executará quando a Thread que chamou o método primeiro terminar de ser executada.

Consegui executar da forma que eu gostaria que executasse através desta forma:

```
try {
    firstCompetitor.start();
    firstCompetitor.join();

    secondCompetitor.start();
    secondCompetitor.join();

    thirdCompetitor.start();
    thirdCompetitor.join();

    fourthCompetitor.start();
    fourthCompetitor.join();

    fifthCompetitor.start();
    fifthCompetitor.join();

    sixthCompetitor.start();
    sixthCompetitor.join();
} catch(InterruptedException exception) {
    System.out.println(exception.toString());
}
```

Mas gostaria de sincronizar através do bloco syncronized(this). Li em alguns tópicos na internet que para fazer isso funcionar deve-se fazer o lock do objeto que quisermos sincronizar, fazendo com que a instância que for executar o método trave até que a instância que chamou primeiro termine de executar.

Answer (score 0):

Vou ser breve que estou no celular.

Com join() está errado porque os threads executam um de cada vez e  não é isso que você quer.

Seu código tem dois outros erros.

Primeiro,  o bloco synchronized está sendo a corrida inteira de cada veículo (ele está fora do for,  deveria estar dentro).

Segundo, tem que sincronizar sobre o mesmo objeto. Você está sincronizando sobre this, só que cada Competitor é um objeto diferente e portanto não ocorre disputa por recursos.

Comment: Ah, estou entendendo. Irei ajeitar essa primeira parte que está errada.

Em relação ao segundo erro, como eu poderia fazer a sincronização do mesmo objeto? Eu tentei passar um objeto de Competitor, mas na main me retorna uma exceção.

Comment: Vou dar uma sugestão que não é muito bonita,  mas é o melhor que posso pensar no momento: crie uma variável global de classe (public static final Object) e use-a nos synchronized. O seu design das duas últimas classes está errado, mas não posso ver isso agora.

Comment: Conseguir fazer dessa forma que você disse. Também consegui passando como parâmetro no synchronized a minha classe, desta forma:

Class.forName("Competitors");

Porém, depois de fazer vários testes, percebi que a sincronização não é 100% precisa. Tem vezes que o firstCompetitor (que chamou primeiro) é o primeiro que executa, e tem vezes que o secondCompetitor (que chamou segundo) é o primeiro que executar.

Comment: Novas dúvidas, novas perguntas.

Comment: E não esqueça de aceitar esta resposta, se ela tiver lhe atendido.